# How to work with profits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now users have the ability to submit Items to the site via form. The information it collects is the buy price, sell price, and quantity. From there, I calculate the profit like this:

```
<td><%= number_with_delimiter(((item.soldfor - item.boughtfor) * item.quantity)) %></td>
```

What I want to do next is display the profits for all of the items the user has posted over a certain time frame like this:

> All time: 1,000,000 | Today: 102,111 | This week: 200,111

The problem is that profit is just a calculation and I can't call upon it anywhere else. How can I organize the calculation of profits in a fashion that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write a method on the `Item` model to return profit:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def profit
    (soldfor.to_f - boughtfor.to_f) * quantity.to_f  ## or use .to_i if you prefer integers
  end
  ...
end
```

And then in your view you can call:

```
<td><%= number_with_delimiter(item.profit) %></td>
```

Or if you want to get the total profit for everything in an `@items` collection:

```
@items.sum(&:profit)
```

So in your case, you would probably do something like this in the controller:

```
@all_time_items  = Item.where(<conditions for all_time>)
@this_week_items = @all_time_items.where(<conditions for this_week>)
@today_items     = @this_week_items.where(<conditions for today>)
```

And then in your view:

```
All time: <%= @all_time_items.sum(&:profit) %> | Today: <%= @today_items.sum(&:profit) %> | This week: <%= @this_week_items.sum(&:profit) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to call method dynamically? 
Then wright on the helper method

```
def number_with_delimite(soldfor,boughtfor,quantity)
  (soldfor - boughtfor) * quantity)
end
```

and here you can call method with condition of  date and time

```
number_with_delimite(item.soldfor.item.boughtfor,item.quantity)
```